# React Router on pages with URLs that are not known in advance

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a massive preexisting website into which some new pages are going to be added that are being built on (client-side) ReactJS.  The routes at which the new ReactJS pages will live are deep in the site:  The ReactJS pages have to play nice with the existing URL structure, and that means that in a lot of cases, they won't *know* what their base URL is until they're deployed to production.  (In some cases, they *still* won't know, because the upper parts of the URLs, the parts before the ReactJS page, are parameterized and will be changing on the fly.)

However, React Router seems to like absolute paths, and doesn't seem to play well with partial/relative/unknown paths.  I've solved this by querying `document.location.pathname` upfront when everything loads — but it feels clunky, like React Router should be able to handle these kinds of relative paths out-of-the-box.

So here's my code, which *does* work:

```
const baseRoute = document.location.pathname;

...

render() {
    return <Router>
        <Route path={baseRoute} component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
            <Route path={baseRoute + "/sub-page1"} component={SubPage1}/>
            <Route path={baseRoute + "/sub-page2"} component={SubPage2}/>
            <Route path={baseRoute + "/*"} component={NotFoundPage}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>;
}

...

render() {
    return <div>
        <IndexLink to={baseRoute}>Home</IndexLink>
        | <Link to={baseRoute + "/sub-page1"}>Sub-Page 1</IndexLink>
        | <Link to={baseRoute + "/sub-page2"}>Sub-Page 2</IndexLink>
    </div>;
}
```

But this seems like a very clunky, brute-force way to handle it.  It means that anything that needs a path needs to have access to that `baseRoute` variable, which is computed once at startup.  It means that everything that uses routing needs to remember to use the `baseRoute` variable as well.  And, to make matters worse, the code can't really be as simple as what I have above, since the incoming URL *could* contain a child route that only React Router knows about, so in some cases, string massaging is needed to properly compute the `baseRoute`.

It looks like they may have solved this issue more generally in React Router 4 by adding a `basename` property, but we're on React Router 3 right now.

**So is there a better solution in React Router 3 to the app being hosted at an unknown URL, or are we stuck with passing around a derived `baseRoute` property?**

Comment: i have a similar situation as you're describing here and my solution is to create the `browserHistory` (instead of importing it) and pass it an object with the `basename` property. the tricky part here is that i need to agree with the host about an `appName` (shared key word between us) so i can parse down the URL up to that key word (with that word included) and this will be my `basename`, every route from now on will not change that `basename`. my `App` `Route` will get a `/` as a path though.